# Update current stable Debian Wheezy system to Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, apt, debian-jessie

[Debian Jessie](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianJessie) just came out as stable.

Is a `apt-get dist-upgrade` enough? Or do I need to do something more, or even use a script like Ubuntu uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this official Debian document](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.dist-upgrade.html) titled “Upgrading from One Stable Distribution to the Next” simply running `apt-get dist-upgrade` should do the trick.

That said, they also recommend `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to the correct repo for package updates. Changing all references from “Wheezy” to “Jessie” if needed; if they are all set to “Stable” no need to change anything. And then running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` prior to running `apt-get dist-upgrade` to ensure all installed packages are up-to-date prior to a core OS upgrade.

Personally, manually changing `/etc/apt/sources.list` for an upgrade like this seems like a bit of overkill, so I wouldn’t worry too much about it. Just go ahead with `apt-get dist-upgrade` and all should be good.

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade you should read the release notes for Debian Jessie and follow the instructions there.
You need to change your sources.list file, upgrade and then run dist-upgrade. Between that you may need to purge some packages as well.

For your convenience, here is a link to the release notes: https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/releasenotes

Answer (score 0):

I did this upgrade recently (Debian Wheezy to Debian Jessie) and all i had to do was:

- change the /etc/apt/sources.list (replace all occurencies of "wheezy" to "jessie")
- run
  apt-get update
- run
  apt-get dist-upgrade
- reboot

After that i had a very functional Jessie.